# Alien-arena does not appear in the launcher

Tags: gnome, software-installation

I have installed the alien-arena via ubuntu programs central and it does not appear at the launcher (press super and type alien),I need always run alien-arena on terminal.
how I can make it appear in the launcher?

Answer (score -1):

Open gedit and add the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Name=alien-arena  
Comment=alien-arena  
Exec=alien-arena  
Icon=alien-arena  
Terminal=false  
X-MultipleArgs=false  
Type=Application  
Categories=Game;ArcadeGame;
```

Save this file as `alien-arena.desktop` on your desktop or in the folder you want.
Give it the permission to be executed as program; in konsole (or terminal), type:

```
chmod +x /path to file/name of file
```

example, if it is on desktop, type:

```
chmod +x ~/desktop/alien-arena.desktop
```

(If you receive a prompt "acces denied" or something like this use `sudo`:
 `sudo chmod +x ~/desktop/alien-arena.desktop`).

Or you can do this graphicaly by right clicking on the shortcut icon then property then permission tab then check: Allow executing file as program.

If you want to have an icon on unity lateral launcher bar, you can drag the game shortcut to the place you want on that launcher and release the mouse button.

That's all, I hope this help.